# Does Chrome Dev Tools has multiple panes?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In Sublime Text you can split screen to multiple panes:

[image]

Can Chrome Dev Tools (Source tab) do that?

Something like that:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, the answer is "no".